# Javascript JSON Loop not counting more than 1 entry

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am reading some json code and at the end added a log that would give me the id. 
My problem is that although there are 2 entries the log is only counting 1 and stops there.

```
var json = [{"main":[{
    "id" : "1", 
    "msg"   : "hi",
    "tid" : "2013-05-05 23:35",
    "fromWho": "hello1@email.se"
},
{
    "id" : "2", 
    "msg"   : "there",
    "tid" : "2013-05-05 23:45",
    "fromWho": "hello2@email.se"
}]}];

for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    var obj = json[i];

    console.log(obj['main'][i].id);
}
```

Why is it only counting the 1 and not the 2 ?

Comment: Because json is an array with 1 element. That element contains another array of objects.

Comment: That's not JSON, that's a JavaScript array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few of the answers here are going to confuse the hell out of you! They're missing the fact that you have an array within an object within an array.

- `json` is an array, with 1 element
- that object has a property `main` which itself is an array
- it is this "3rd level" array which you are trying to loop through

```js
var json = [{"main":[{
    "id" : "1", 
    "msg"   : "hi",
    "tid" : "2013-05-05 23:35",
    "fromWho": "hello1@email.se"
},
{
    "id" : "2", 
    "msg"   : "there",
    "tid" : "2013-05-05 23:45",
    "fromWho": "hello2@email.se"
}]}];

for(var i = 0; i < json[0].main.length; i++) {
    var obj = json[0].main[i];

    console.log(obj.id);
}
```

Comment: I noticed this, it's weird that this isn't just an object by itself. So many layers (like an onion).

Answer (score 1):

This happens because your array contains one object. I guess you need to access the `main` property:

```
for(var i = 0; i < json[0].main.length; i++) {
    console.log(json[0].main[i].id);
}
```

```js
var json = [{"main":[{
    "id" : "1", 
    "msg"   : "hi",
    "tid" : "2013-05-05 23:35",
    "fromWho": "hello1@email.se"
},
{
    "id" : "2", 
    "msg"   : "there",
    "tid" : "2013-05-05 23:45",
    "fromWho": "hello2@email.se"
}]}];

for(var i = 0; i < json[0].main.length; i++) {
    console.log(json[0].main[i].id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an array with 1 element ( 'main' ) and in the 'main' you have an array with 2 elements
Change to this:

```
  for(var i = 0; i < json[0].length; i++) {      
        console.log(json[0][i].id);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`json` is an array of object. So `json[0]` will return the `main` object

Use [**forEach**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to loop through the array

```
var _getMain = json[0].main // will return main array;
_getMain.forEach(function(item){
document.write('<pre>'+item.id+'</pre>')
})
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/vrtpkgqg/)

Answer (score -1):

Because you have to loop through json[0].main, not through json...